# Expressjs static space in file name trailing slash

Tags: express, static

I use express to serve static files on local disk.

`app.use('/media/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'media'), {redirect: false}))`

And under `media` folder, I have a folder named `image files`. In that folder, I have a file called `image.png`.

When I use `http://localhost:3000/media/image%20files/image.png` in the address field of my browser, express always redirect the request to `http://localhost:3000/media/image%20files/image.png/` that adding a trailing slash.

If I remove the space in the folder name, it serves the image file.

What I did wrong? Is this a bug?

Thanks,

Comment: The version of the browser? Local OS?

Comment: latest chrome, MacOS

Comment: I just tested it on a clean install Express (just added your line to include the static folder). Neither on chrome, nor on safari, such behavior does not happen. This is the specific behavior of your local environment. Or you did not tell us the additional configurations of your application.

Comment: yes. It is weird. I created a clean file and could not reproduce the problem initially. Then I made a typo in the URL, after that the problem appeared. But I think it is not express. It is Chrome somehow persist a cache and always redirect to a '/'ed version. Clear chrome cache and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question so if anyone runs into the same issue they have a possible answer.

I cleared Chrome cache and the problem is gone.